# Python Fabric 2 use stdin

Tags: python, fabric

how do I pass stdin to a remote command using fabric?

I want to invoke something with `mycommand -` and provide stdin. I don't want to use a remote file because I want to avoid having to delete that.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but from the docs `run` has an `in_stream` parameter that you can pass a file-like object to.

Comment: thanks. missed that in the documentation

Comment: it just hangs if I do it like that: `Connection("host").run("command -", in_stream = io.BytesIO("input data".encode("UTF-8"))`

Comment: found this issue https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/553